# What's the maximum records mysql can handle concurrently?

Tags: php, mysql

My application is built on PHP and MYSQL. I am expecting to have more than 10,000 concurrents user to submit the registration form concurrently. For that, do I need to have paid license for mysql or can free version be able to handle? Any special configurations do i need to tune up for mysql? Or Is it just depending on my server's setup and scripts?

Please suggest.

Comment: This has more to do with hardware than licensing. As such, it may be a better candidate for ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask there.

Comment: By "10,000 concurrent users" do you mean you expect over 10,000 HTTP form submissions within a few seconds, and this would happen 24/7? I don't think there's any website in the world that busy, with the possible exception of google.com. Can you provide more detail about your expected use-case?

Comment: Hello Dai, thanks for your answer. It won't happen 24/7 or all the time. It may happen in some peak hours such as when we run promotions for certain time only. For example, we ran some products give away campaign for certain time, users have to fill in the subscription form to be listed, due to the short time, users peak can spike around thousands+

Comment: @knightrider: You are overestimating your peak load by a **lot**.

Comment: If you have that number of customers do no expect a freebie.

Comment: Hello Thanks, I am not expecting a freebie. I just want to make sure whether do I need to get a paid license from mysql.

Comment: A paid license won't give you any more performance, it just gives you the right to call Oracle support. You should probably look into clustering or sharding to distribute the load

Comment: i did this type of project 1 yr ago like this   1. first write to xml file.  then slowly  move data from xml to database by crone

Answer (score 1):

As i seen some comment from @Dai he is correct and i am agree with him

but though you can set in mysql configuration to set your connection limit per second

here is very good documentation to set mysql basic configuration in your site

Please refer this [LINK](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/01/06/mysql-high-number-connections-per-secon/)

Also if want  some Script just go throw this [Blog](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=34588)

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: why vote down ? is there anything wrong ? i am just trying to help @knightrider.

Comment: am not the down voter but this answer doesn't satisfy the question neither the links describe it better

Comment: stack overflow is not to give exact code. it is for help purpose, if you need that code pls hire some professional

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms I think mysql team may be never thought about 10,000 access per second. I think it is not a possible thing. And also your peak time is not coming to you when the moment you launched the site. so just be cool and do your sql part. according to the site traffic change your hardware resources to handle the performance. for a hint just go with sql commit,rollback and block.  Thanks.